# Get value from a link or text box in a list using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have the following script ,

```
   <script>

  $().ready(function(){ 

    $('.request_list').click(function(){
      requesting_dept = $('#requesting_department_name').val();
      alert(requesting_dept); 

      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>pharm_profile/user_requests_detials/"+requesting_dept,
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(request_list) {               
          request_list_details = $('#request_list_details').empty(); 

          if(request_list === null){ 
            request_list_detials.append("<ul>No Active Requests</ul>"); 
          } else {
            $.each(request_list, function(i, request_list){  

              request_list_details.append('<tr><td><span="font_color:white !important;">'+request_list.department_name+'</span></td>\n\
              <td><span style="color:red !important;">'+request_list.commodity_name+'</span></td>\n\
              <td> <span style="color:red !important;">'+request_list.total_quantity_requested+'</span></td>\n\
              <td> <span style="color:red !important;">'+request_list.request_order_id+'</span></td>\n\
              <td> <span style="color:red !important;">'+request_list.date_added+'</span></td> \n\
              <td> <a class="approve" id="approve" href="#stock_details">Approve/Issue </a><input type="hidden" name="request_order_id" value='+request_list.request_order_id+' /></td>\n\
              </tr>');
            });
          }
        },
        error: function(data) {
        }
      });     
    });
  });        
</script>
```

The  script is supposed to pick a value from a hidden html text field which from the  following html unordered list

```
<ul><a class="request_list"  id="request_list" href="#active_request_list">'+request.department_name+'</a><input value="'+request.department_name+'" id="requesting_department_name" type="hidden" class="requesting_department_name"/></ul>
```

How can I get the  value from the input field of department using  jquery described above?

Comment: Please, *please* fix your formatting. Nobody wants to read that.

Comment: Just post the specific piece of code.

Comment: One of the worst formatting i found soo far

Comment: Better if you make demo of this code on JSFIDDLE or any site similar to this so we can easily understand your code.

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to understand so much lines of code but will try to provide an idea...

```
 $().ready(function() {
    $('.request_list').click(function() {
       var a = $(this);
       var requesting_dept = a.html();
       var requesting_inpVal = a.parent().find("input.requesting_department_name").val();
       ...
       ...
       ...
```